# Android: String does't Match when compared with string in File

Tags: java, android, string

***My Code:***

```
    FileNames:
    public interface FileNames {
    String BACKUP_FILE ="backup";
    }
```

***backupsave.java:**
Writing to the file(Saving the file):

```
  public void onSave2(View view)
{

    try{
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save2);
        ev2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EV2);
        String backup = FileNames.BACKUP_FILE;
        FileOutputStream outputStream;
        outputStream = openFileOutput(backup,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        outputStream.write(ev2.getText().toString().getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
        Log.d("TAG","data saved"+openFileInput(backup).read());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Backup Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here, I do get a toast "Backup Saved" and log as data saved97

***backup.java***
Reading from the File:

```
    public void onLogin(View view) {
    try{
        String backup = FileNames.BACKUP_FILE;
        String str1 = ev1.getText().toString();
        FileInputStream inputStream;
        inputStream = openFileInput(backup);
        Log.d("TAG", "File Read" + inputStream.read());
        if((inputStream.read()!=-1)&& str1.equals(inputStream.read())) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Backup matched", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            inputStream.close();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Backup does not work", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            backup.this.finish();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here,i get a Log message which says "File Read97"
and a toast that Backup doesn't work.
Please HELP !!!!

Comment: where is ev1 in your code? and why temp is integer?

Comment: ev1 is text taken from edittext

Comment: and temp is an integer because my edit text accepts only numerical data

Comment: how is an integer will be equal to string without typecasting?

Comment: String str1 = String.valueOf(ev1);

Comment: this will work but you are not doing this with temp

Comment: then how can I make it work?

Comment: str1.equals(String.valueOf(temp))

Comment: i tried it! Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//in backupsave.java
String str = ev2.getText().toString();
```

And this

```
//in backup.java
BufferedInputStream stream=new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
byte[] result=new byte[stream.count];
int tmp=stream.read(result,0,stream.count);
if(tmp!=-1)
{
     String finalr=new String(result);
     if(str1.equals(finalr))
     {
     //etc
```

And i don't know what are you doing, but you are saving ev2 and comparing with ev1, it can be a problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in those lines

```
String str1 = String.valueOf(ev1);
...
int temp = inputStream.read();
...
if((inputStream.read()!=-1)&& str1.equals(temp)) {
```

- `str1` - contains the string you expect
- `temp` - contains the first byte of the saved file
- `str1.equals(temp)` - will always return `false` as you try to check a `String` and a `Integer` object for equality

**edit** When you write/read text files it's better to use `FileWriter` and `FileReader`.

Find a snippet below

```
String text = "some text";
try (BufferedWriter fw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"))) {
    fw.write(text);
}

try (BufferedReader fr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("output.txt"))) {
    String in = fr.readLine();
    System.out.println("check = " + in.equals(text));
}
```

output of the snippet

```
check = true
```